# grep from a input file, multiple lines while the input file has ^name

Tags: linux, grep, match

I would really appreciate some help with this:

I have a huge file, I will give you an example of how it is formatted:

```
name:lastname:email
```

I have a input file with lots of names set out like this example:

```
edward
michael
jenny
```

I want to match to name column from the huge file to the name in the input file, and only if it is an exact match (case insensitive)

Once it finds a match I want it to output a .txt with all of the matchs

I think I can use a command something like `^Michael:` to give it.

Can anyone help me with this grep problem?

sorry if I am not too clear its very late and I have been on this problem for ages

```
"Centos 5, "grep -i -E -f file.txt /root/dir2search >out.txt"

file.txt containing
^michael:
^bobert:
^billy:
```

Doesn't find anything.

Comment: Is the format of the input file under your control, and is it necessary to do this in a single grep? It would be easier if the input were in a slightly different form.

Comment: Hi S McCrohan The input can be changed easily but the file I want it matching with is too big to be edited. What could you suggest?

Answer (score 7):

`grep -i -E -f inputfile namesfile > outputfile` will do what you want, if your input file consists of one input name per line, in the pattern you already suggested:

```
^Michael:
^Jane:
^Tom:
```

`-i`: case-insensitive matching

`-E`: regexp pattern matching (often the default, but I don't know how your environment is set up)

`-f`: read patterns from a file, one pattern per line

`>`: redirect the output to a file

To get the existing input file you described (space-separated names) into the new format, you could use:
`sed -r 's/([^ ]+)[ $]?/^\1:\n/g;s/\n$//g' inputfile > newinputfile`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying your suggestion at the moment (Takes along time as file is so big)

Comment: For testing, consider using just a portion of the target file. Assuming you're in a fairly typical Unix environment, you could do something like: `head -50 namesfile | grep -i -E -f inputfile > outputfile` to grep against only the first 50 lines of the target file.

Comment: Also don't leave blank line in the input file, as that would match all lines in the output...

Comment: @Marki555 Thanks for the info, the empty line wasted a lot of time until I saw  your comment